# How to specify a certificate alias for a ResteasyClient/HttpClient keystore?

Tags: java, ssl, resteasy, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm looking at the docs for the [ResteasyClientBuilder](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0-rc-1/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/client/jaxrs/ResteasyClientBuilder.html), in which there is the ability to specify a client keystore for 2-way SSL handshaking/authentication.

There is a method [`keystore()`](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0-rc-1/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/client/jaxrs/ResteasyClientBuilder.html#keyStore(java.security.KeyStore,%20java.lang.String)) to specify the keystore (path + keystore password) as well as the private key for the client certificate.  However, how do I specify the alias of the key that I want to use?

Given the the ResteasyClient leverages the HttpClient, I see the same issue in Apache's [`SSLSocketFactory`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html) constructors.

Is there anyway to specify an alias in either framework?  Does this client keystore need to have only a single certificate pair?  I don't see any options to specify an alias anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the alias to use by supplying a `PrivateKeyStrategy` to an `SSLContextBuilder` if you can use Apache HttpComponents.

```
private SSLContext createContext(String keyStorePath, String keyStorePassword, String privateKeyAlias) {
    final char[] password = keyStorePassword.toCharArray();
    // This keyStore could also come from `file.toURI().toURL();`
    final URL keyStore = Application.class.getClassLoader().getResource(keyStorePath);

    return SSLContextBuilder.create()
            .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, password, password, (aliases, socket) -> privateKeyAlias)
            .loadTrustMaterial(keyStore, password)
            .build();
}
```

If you need to use the context to connect to multiple end points, you can change the function `(alias, socket) -> "aliasToUse"` to suit your needs.